# MySQL Error 2013 for only a few specific queries. Is the data corrupt?

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error on my MySQL server:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server
```

This occurs when I run the following command: `select * from users where id=664;`
This error ONLY comes up when selecting a user with an ID of **664** up to **709**. EVERY OTHER USER WORKS.

This just randomly started up about a week ago and I got some complaints from users not being able to login because of this. I can see their user data when using `select *` without limited it to an id.

What can be causing this issue, and how can I repair it?

If it matters:

- Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64
- MySQL Server version: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 (Ubuntu)
- Laravel 9.17.0
- All other packages are up to date.

Comment: Run `mysqlcheck` I'd also be looking to see if the server itself restarted and to check it's logs, I would also run the query locally, and select individual columns.

Comment: That worked to show me what the issue was. I was able to fix it by backing up the corrupt table then installing it again.

Comment: In that case, I'll set it as an answer...